# Properties of $n \times n$ complex matrix with $A^m = I$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

> If $A^m = I_n$ then what can we say about the eigenvalues and diagonalizablity of $A$?

The equation given above is an annihilating polynomial of $A$ and therefore minimal polynomial divides it. Since the roots of the polynomial are distinct in complex field. Hence it is diagonalizable with each eigenvalue being some root of unity. Am I correct?

Comment: Yes, it is diagonalisable, for the reason you give.

Comment: Thanks and what about the nature of eigenvalues? @LordSharktheUnknown

Comment: Same : eigenvalues are roots of the minimal polynomial, therefore they must be roots of unity.